# upgrade declined

Tags: upgrade

Recently there was a bubble that appeared saying that the new ubuntu upgrade is available, I declined it, clicking do not remind again, I am now having trouble starting and finding the upgrade link, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: What version are you using and what do you want to update to?

Answer (score 0):

In the Terminal, type in

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This will tell you if a new OS is available.

I'll try and come up with a fix

## Edit

In Terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo update-manager -d
```

Then follow the instructions to upgrade

Comment: Whenever I use terminal the following appears...     'pete is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported. ' I have 12.10 64bit, looking 2 upgrade 2 ubuntu 13 64bit (latest), as 12.10 64bitdoes not work so well 4 me I have concluded. * When trying 2 install heimdall, in software center, clicking install button it shows install progress, looks 2 be installing, shows install progress, then fails showing install button once more, hoping ubuntu 13 (latest) 64bit works better for me, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using lubuntu, I am sure that this works same for the ubuntu even

from the menu bar on the left you see system settings, once you open that you can see softwares and updates icon at the bottom.

If you click on that there you find the bubble that you are looking for @pete